# TransformPdfFields does not work even on setting DefaultRecipient to true

Tags: docusignapi

I have a pdf with some signature and text form fields. Uploading this pdf on docusign appdemo link finds as well as replaces these fields with docusign tabs which means pdf is fine. But when I send same pdf using docusign api rest call (v2), it delivers document without the tabs. The json structure that I am sending is as below with both transformPdfFields for document and DefaultRecipient for Recipient set to true:

```js
{
"EnvelopeId":null,
"EmailBlurb":"You have some documents to be signed...",
"EmailSubject":"Please Sign",
"Status":"Sent",
"CompositeTemplates":
[{
 "InlineTemplates":
 [{
  "Sequence":"1",
  "Documents":
  [{
   "DocumentId":"1",
   "Name":"Agreement.pdf",
   "DocumentFields":[],
   "TransformPdfFields":"true",
   "Order":"1",
   "FileExtension":"pdf",
   "DocumentBase64":"fileContent"
  }],
  "Recipients":
  {
   "Signers":
   [{
    "RecipientId":"8",
    "SignedDateTime":null,
    "Status":null,
    "Email":"test@test.com",
    "Name":"Vidhi Khanna",
    "DefaultRecipient":"true",
    "CustomFields":null
   }]
  }
 }]
}]
}
```

I also tried the same thing with json structure for create and send envelope using document (i.e. no template involved), but that also doesn't work.

**P.S.** One thing that I should mention is that I am using a test developer account for the integration. Is it possible that this feature is not enabled for demo account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformPdfFields functionality only works when used on a document element directly within the CompositeTemplate.  For example:

```
{
"EnvelopeId":null,
"EmailBlurb":"You have some documents to be signed...",
"EmailSubject":"Please Sign",
"Status":"Sent",
"CompositeTemplates":
[{
    "InlineTemplates":
    [{
        "Sequence":"1",
        "Recipients":
        {
            "Signers":
            [{
                "RecipientId":"8",
                "SignedDateTime":null,
                "Status":null,
                "Email":"test@test.com",
                "Name":"Vidhi Khanna",
                "DefaultRecipient":"true",
                "CustomFields":null
            }]
        }
    }],
    "document":
    {
        "DocumentId":"1",
        "Name":"Agreement.pdf",
        "DocumentFields":[],
        "TransformPdfFields":"true",
        "Order":"1",
        "FileExtension":"pdf",
        "DocumentBase64":"fileContent"
    }
}]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff. That definitely solved my problem. Although, this means if I need to pass multiple documents in this envelope, I need to add multiple composite templates i.e. one per document.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I heard some mention that transformPdfFields might be intended to work in the fashion you were using but in today's state you'll need to use multiple composite templates.

Comment: Any idea how to do this when creating a template? This looks to be just for creating an envelope.